# The :w command is not working in vi - Why?

Tags: vi

I am trying to edit a html file with vi. I made my changes and am now trying to use the :w command to write these to the file. However, the text :w is just being typed on the screen. On the bottom of the terminal, it also says -- INSERT --

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: press escape a few times .. try pressing Control-D.. also type :vi<Enter> .. either this is a messed up terminal , or you are in 'ex' mode..

Comment: Did you pressed ESC before `:w` to switch to normal mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the `Escape` key to leave the insert mode. You should then be able to type `:w` then hit `Enter` and see that the file is written.

You should check out this [beginnner tutorial for vi](http://www.linfo.org/vi/).

Also, try using `vim`. It has all of the features of `vi` plus more! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159206/difference-between-vi-vim).

If you choose to upgrade to `vim`, check out [this interactive `vim` tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html).